# Is there a way to communicate over TCPIP on Matlab running without Java Support

Tags: matlab, tcp

I'm working in Monkeylogic (extension of matlab) but it requires there be no java support to get better time resolution.  I also need to communicate to another comp over ethernet but the tcpip commands in matlab require java support.  Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C/C++ you can create a client/server socket class and compile it into mex-files and uses those to talk back and forth to MatLab, but that might not be much better than Java.